# Cómo ejecutar reader a través de un método génerico

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo un método el cual me ayuda a ejecutar un sp y devuelve un reader:

```
public object EjecutarReaderStoredProcedure(string textoComando)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoComando.Trim()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("No se especificó el comando", "string textoComando");
    }

    IDataReader reader = null;
    IDbCommand comando = null;
    try
    {
        this.conexion.Open();
        comando = PrepararComando(textoComando, CommandType.StoredProcedure, null);
        comando.CommandTimeout = 0;
        reader = comando.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {

        comando.Dispose();
        comando = null;
    }
    return reader;
}
```

Cómo puedo leer los datos de ese método en una pagina de .net ya que lo hago de esta manera pero solo me devuelve `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`

```
AdministraAccesoDatos ad = new AdministraAccesoDatos("xxx",SqlServer);
object dr= ad.EjecutarReaderStoredProcedure("SP_MostrarVariables");
ViewBag.MuestraVariables = dr;
```

Comment: Por qué `object dr`? usa `var dr` o mejor en este caso, `DataReader`

Comment: @Pikoh si pongo SqlDataReader dr= ad.EjecutarReaderStoredProcedure("SP_MostrarVariables");
me dice que no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo object en sqldatareader. ya existe una conversion explicita

Comment: Lógicamente. Porque tu método `EjecutarReaderStoredProcedure` devuelve `object` no se muy bien porqué. Cambia el tipo devuelto de ese método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas iterar sobre el `IDataReader` para poder obtener lo datos del mismo utilizando el metodo `NextResult()` con un `while`.

Por ejemplo imagina que ejecutas un sql que deseas obtener los nombres de la tabla persona. Esto se haria de la siguiente manera:

```
AdministraAccesoDatos ad = new AdministraAccesoDatos("xxx",SqlServer);
IDataReader dr= ad.EjecutarReaderStoredProcedure("SP_MostrarVariables");
List<string> nombres = new List<string>();
while(dr.NextResult())
{
   var nombre = dr.GetString(r.GetOrdinal("nombre"));
   nombres.add(nombre);
}

ViewBag.nombres = nombres;
```

Nota que el metodo `NextResult()` retornara true siempre y cuando haya datos para iterar. El metodo `GetString(ordinal)`  te retorna el dato del indice indicado y para obtener el indice de la columan que deseas se utiliza el metodo `GetOrdinal`.

Comment: si funciono gracias!!!!